# Gradle project refresh failed- Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

I just installed Android Studio 2.2 and from start I am getting this error.

> Error: Process 'command'/usr/local/android-studio/jre/bin/java" finished with non-zero exit value 2

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to you have not installed properly Oracle Java SDK 8? Please follow steps described here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: It is working.. Actually i did not setup the Studio Correctly.. Checked my Java was working.. So didn't try to mess with the jdk settings in the studio.. Sorry didn't update it.. My bad.. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem. It's because of wrong path selected by android-studio of JDK. Anyway, you can fix it by setting the path of JDK.

You can do it by opening Configure → Project Default → Project Structure inside Android Studio and set path of JDK.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhj3MY4SpHY) by [Miguel Arcila](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDXH1BqfWzd7ivrTWsGgEqw). The steps to fixing the problem are:

1. Open File Menu.
2. Go to Project Structure.
3. Uncheck "Use Embedded JDK (recommended)".
4. Browse through your filesystem and select where JDK is installed. It could be `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_112` or a similar directory.