# Help! Can't choose a valid JDK for Android Studio, so my Gradle is Failing. Why?

Tags: 32-bit, jdk, android-studio, ubuntu-make

So I've been at this for a few hours now, and I must admit that I give up.

I know from looking up (so this isn't exactly a duplicate) that I need to change the directory of the JDK. Mad props to this guy "BHAGYARSH DHUMAL"(in "[Gradle project refresh failed- Android Studio 2.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/828328/gradle-project-refresh-failed-android-studio-2-2)") for coming up with what he said, because I was originally looking at /$HOME$/.local/... for which there was never any .local directory anyway.

So I took some advice from http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux in terms of how to make sure I was running Oracle Java and not Openjdk (just in case, and to make sure I had "the Java" JDK).

However, I go to the /....oracle-java-8-jdk/jre folder and try to select it like Mr. Dhumal said... and it says "please choose a valid JDK environment." 
Uhm, ok......

Seems like I can't be that far from the right way of doing this, but I just can't crack it. I need this to be working so I can write an Android Application for school in the next six weeks or so.
Any help please?

P.S. I'd ask by comment perhaps on Mr. Dhumal's post, but I have waaaay too low reputation to do that (TAT).

Thanks in advance!

p.p.s. it is 3am here, so I'm going to bed. I won't be around for maybe another five hours at least.

Comment: Have you tried just installing Android Studio using Ubuntu Make?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I did with sudo umake android in terminal, followed by the GUI installer.

Comment: Hey, Andrea. Thanks for the help! I figured out what was wrong.

Although it also worth noting that if using the 32-bit kernel OS, you are also quite limited in which version of the Android Build Tools you are using. It seems the compiling to make a debug APK for a testing device requires that the adb version not exceed 23.0.3... so yeah, that's another important note.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, many thanks to Mr. Sujal (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279790/sujal) for his help over on the Discord community.

The solution was quite simple.

It involves not choosing the "jre" folder (of /....oracle-java-8-jdk/jre), but instead choosing the jdk folder one level above it.

All in all, a very simple fix, even if it took an hour to figure out.

Many thanks to him again, and while he says he never uses Stack Overflow, I hope he will get to know how much I appreciate his help.